# Can Auth0 JWT Tokens Be Used to Send POST Requests to Django Backend?

Tags: django, post, jwt, token, auth0

I was unable to find any valid documentation for the last 5-6 days on how to resolve my issue of sending POST-requests to a JWT (Auth0) secured API backend built on Django.

I hope someone can help to verify if sending POST-requests is at all possible or what alternatives I may look at.

My current issue stems from a supposed final major bug with using Auth0 JWT Tokens, through the Client Credential Flow M2M method. Though I may understand that I am using a very unique setup:

1. React Frontend
2. Django Backend
3. No user login intended to access secured API access

---

I guess it just now leads me to questioning on whether simply, **“Can I even send POST requests to a Auth0 JWT Token secured backend?”**. If it is possible, hope someone may redirect me to a potential solution, else, at least I know I really need to source something else entirely.

The potential solutions I do only see with a React frontend, is to actually build a:

- Express.js backend
- Enable user-account login access

This would not be ideal as both options are not the intended use case, and it will dramatically require me to change extensive code, especially to rebuild an entire backend. I was suppose to launch 2-3 weeks ago, but apparently now, this is the last security roadblock I am facing.

Hope some kind soul may help to redirect me on a potential solution on how can I send POST requests, with JWT Token validation, to a Django backend?

The current code I am using is as follows, and sadly, the GET option works, but this POST request option doesn’t seem to work:

```
let getBackendConfig = {
            headers: { 
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_JWT_AUTH0_HEADER + " " + auth0Token,
            },
        };



async function submitLocationViaPOST( dataToPOST ) {
            setIsLocationUploaded("process");
            try {
                Promise.all([
                    await axios
                        .post(urlSubmitLocationPOSTAPI, dataToPOST, getBackendConfig)
                        .then(response => {
                            console.log(" urlSubmitLocationPOSTAPI Reply Data: ", response);
                            if (response.status === 201) {
                                // EXECUTE ONLY IF RESPONSE IS "201" --- MEANING ENTRY CREATED SUCCESSFULLY
                                setIsLocationUploaded("finish");
                            }
                        })
                ]);
            }
            catch (err) {
                setIsLocationUploaded("error");
                console.log(" urlSubmitLocationPOSTAPI Error: " + err);
            }
        }
```

Currently, any GET requests sent to the JWT (Auth0) secured API backend works. However, when I attempt to send a POST request, everything fails.

Given that it is a no-user-account-login process, as well as a Django backend built with Django REST Framework, there isn't much error messages except for the standard 500 error, which will disappear when I disable the JWT authentication process, which will in turn defeat the initial purpose of building in this security measure.

Hope someone with better knowledge on this may help me on this matter. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The client credentials grant is not a secure way to authenticate a SPA and an API. You might as well just leave the API open to the public if there is no user authentication necessary for the SPA to access the information. Anyone can inspect your react app and get your client id and secret, then use it to get an access token for your api.

Comment: Hi @DanWoda, then my question then is how does the M2M Client Credential structure suppose to work? Given that my site is a really basic site that if including a login-system may over-complicate it as it does not have that much of functions in place to require such a function.

Thus, I presumed my system is quite like a system-to-system communication, like M2M, though it is a frontend-to-backend relation. So is the SPA + API the only solution that supposedly fits my scenario just because I am using React in the frontend and Django in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to resolve my issue and just like to redirect a potential solution for those who are stuck with this potential problem.

Long story short, **you CAN send POST Requests through Django backend with JWT Token, just that there are close to zero documentation online on how to do it**. I've searched for 7 days over the same documents on google but didn't manage to find any.

Nonetheless, I have written down my solution in this link, hope it will help anyone who has suffered the "pulling hair effect": https://stackoverflow.com/a/56895558/1140206

Good luck!